# Is Forrest's speech at the anti-war rally available anywhere?

Tags: forrest-gump

Forrest delivers an impromptu speech at an anti-war rally in Washington DC.

The audience of the rally, and us the viewer, did not get the hear this speech due to the mic being disconnected. It is evidentially a moving speech due to the reaction given by those immediately next to him who can hear it.

Is there anywhere that I can hear/read what Forrest said?

Comment: that's because it wasn't hanks that said it, this is a historical reference to an actual speech involving jerry rubin, abbie Hoffman, jane fonda, and I forget the others, in the actual speech a soldier describes how not everyone gets to come home in one piece if at all though like gump there are some difficulties with the speakers thanks to fonda making the only lasting part of his speech the final bit of "that's all I have to say about that"
if anyone can find the recording I'd love to see it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes (apparently).**

According to [Tom Hanks](http://purplenurple.net/what-did-forrest-gump-really-say/), Forrest said:

> “Sometimes when people go to Vietnam,
>   they go home to their mommas without any legs. Sometimes they don’t go
>   home at all. That’s a bad thing. That’s all I have to say about that.”

I say apparently as I can't find a *primary source* for the Tom Hanks quote. It's *everywhere*, but I'd love to find an actual interview where he says it.

Comment: Not sure where they got this from either, because he [clearly starts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcOTZeZ3_40#t=1m43s) with "**In Vietnam, your\you're**..." Apparently there's also a DVD extra with the alternate take out there supporting this (Google: gump speech + alternative take, it's in a couple of e-books), showing that he simply said: "In Vietnam, **your best good friend can get shot**" (and possibly repeating it).

Comment: It's a good point. [This is a reference](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5R7YAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA434&lpg=PA434&dq=In+Vietnam,+your+best+good+friend+can+get+shot&source=bl&ots=J9Wnal9RpP&sig=RFOEgIhsuHhGf6m51LlyahXN1F0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PBl3VISgNMqR7AbBzIDwCQ&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=In%20Vietnam%2C%20your%20best%20good%20friend%20can%20get%20shot&f=false) supporting what you say, so I can definitely see it. I'd love to see a primary source for the Hanks quote in my answer, as it really is *everywhere* online. But I don't know if it's *just* a rumour or if it's based in fact.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't link it directly, code got all wonky when I tried it.

Comment: @Walt: I'd add that as an answer to be honest. I can't find a definitive source for the Tom Hanks quote *anywhere*